# UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have this scenario:

1. fetch (read and delete) a record from **IncomingMessage** table
2. read record content
3. insert something to some tables
4. if an error (any exception) occurred in steps 1-3, insert an error-record to **OutgoingMessage** table
5. otherwise, insert an success-record to **OutgoingMessage** table

*So steps 1,2,3,4 should be in a transaction, or steps 1,2,3,5*

My process starts from here (it is a scheduled task):

```
public class ReceiveMessagesJob implements ScheduledJob {
// ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            processMessageMediator.processNextRegistrationMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
// ...
}
```

My main function (processNextRegistrationMessage) in ProcessMessageMediator:

```
public class ProcessMessageMediatorImpl implements ProcessMessageMediator {
// ...
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void processNextRegistrationMessage() throws ProcessIncomingMessageException {
        String refrenceId = null;
        MessageTypeEnum registrationMessageType = MessageTypeEnum.REGISTRATION;
        try {
            String messageContent = incomingMessageService.fetchNextMessageContent(registrationMessageType);
            if (messageContent == null) {
                return;
            }
            IncomingXmlModel incomingXmlModel = incomingXmlDeserializer.fromXml(messageContent);
            refrenceId = incomingXmlModel.getRefrenceId();
            if (!StringUtil.hasText(refrenceId)) {
                throw new ProcessIncomingMessageException(
                        "Can not proceed processing incoming-message. refrence-code field is null.");
            }
            sqlCommandHandlerService.persist(incomingXmlModel);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof ProcessIncomingMessageException) {
                throw (ProcessIncomingMessageException) e;
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            // send error outgoing-message
            OutgoingXmlModel outgoingXmlModel = new OutgoingXmlModel(refrenceId,
                    ProcessResultStateEnum.FAILED.getCode(), e.getMessage());
            saveOutgoingMessage(outgoingXmlModel, registrationMessageType);
            return;
        }
        // send success outgoing-message
        OutgoingXmlModel outgoingXmlModel = new OutgoingXmlModel(refrenceId, ProcessResultStateEnum.SUCCEED.getCode());
        saveOutgoingMessage(outgoingXmlModel, registrationMessageType);
    }

    private void saveOutgoingMessage(OutgoingXmlModel outgoingXmlModel, MessageTypeEnum messageType)
            throws ProcessIncomingMessageException {
        String xml = outgoingXmlSerializer.toXml(outgoingXmlModel, messageType);
        OutgoingMessageEntity entity = new OutgoingMessageEntity(messageType.getCode(), new Date());
        try {
            outgoingMessageService.save(entity, xml);
        } catch (SaveOutgoingMessageException e) {
            throw new ProcessIncomingMessageException("Can not proceed processing incoming-message.", e);
        }
    }
// ...
}
```

As i said If any exception occurred in steps 1-3, i want insert an error-record:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof ProcessIncomingMessageException) {
        throw (ProcessIncomingMessageException) e;
    }
    e.printStackTrace();
    //send error outgoing-message
    OutgoingXmlModel outgoingXmlModel = new OutgoingXmlModel(refrenceId,ProcessResultStateEnum.FAILED.getCode(), e.getMessage());
    saveOutgoingMessage(outgoingXmlModel, registrationMessageType);
    return;
}
```

It's SqlCommandHandlerServiceImpl.persist() method:

```
public class SqlCommandHandlerServiceImpl implements SqlCommandHandlerService {
// ...
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void persist(IncomingXmlModel incomingXmlModel) {
        Collections.sort(incomingXmlModel.getTables());
        List<ParametricQuery> queries = generateSqlQueries(incomingXmlModel.getTables());
        for (ParametricQuery query : queries) {
            queryExecuter.executeQuery(query);
        }
    }
// ...
}
```

But when **sqlCommandHandlerService.persist()** throws exception (here a org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException exception), after inserting an error-record in OutgoingMessage table, when the transaction want to be committed , i get UnexpectedRollbackException. *I can't figure out where is my problem:*

```
Exception in thread "null#0" org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:717)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:394)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at x.y.z.ReceiveMessagesJob$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$63524c6b.run(<generated>)
    at x.y.z.JobScheduler$ScheduledJobThread.run(JobScheduler.java:132)
```

I'm using hibernate-4.1.0-Final, My database is oracle, and Here is my transaction-manager bean:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    proxy-target-class="true" />
```

Comment: paste complete stackTrace

Comment: I noticed that this exception throwned when repository itself can't do job, not other parts of your code.

Comment: In most cases, this exception is just a summary. If you check your Spring output logs, you'll see some inner exceptions which make the transaction be roll-backed. For example, your entity stores some transient entity and your cascade rules don't handle such a case.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This is the normal behavior and the reason is that your `sqlCommandHandlerService.persist` method needs a TX when being executed (because it is marked with `@Transactional` annotation). But when it is called inside `processNextRegistrationMessage`, because there is a TX available, the container doesn't create a new one and uses existing TX. So if any exception occurs in `sqlCommandHandlerService.persist` method, it causes TX to be set to `rollBackOnly` (even if you catch the exception in the caller and ignore it).

To overcome this you can use propagation levels for transactions. Have a look at [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) to find out which propagation best suits your requirements.

### Update; Read this!

Well after a colleague came to me with a couple of questions about a similar situation, I feel this needs a bit of clarification.
Although propagations solve such issues, you should be *VERY* careful about using them and do not use them unless you *ABSOLUTELY* understand what they mean and how they work. You may end up persisting some data and rolling back some others where you don't expect them to work that way and things can go horribly wrong.

---

**EDIT** [Link to current version of the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html)

Comment: Thanks Ean. I'm not sure using REQUIRES_NEW or NESTED!? (I have tested REQUIRES_NEW and it worked)

Comment: The difference between these two is that, NESTED is like a child TX so if parent gets committed it will get committed otherwise not. REQUIRES_NEW creates a new TX and suspends the existing one. So it gets committed individually. Be careful about your container as these are not supported in all containers. The link above has some explanation about the environments that support these types of propagations.

Comment: if use spring-test and `defaultRolback` is false(@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)), you also could have this exception. To resolve it just need set defaultRollback = true

Comment: Which method is it suggested to add this Propagation configuration to the @Transactional annotation?  SqlCommandHandlerServiceImpl.persist() (and thus require overriding), or processNextRegistrationMessage()?  Does the separate transaction propagation requirement apply to the transactional method that catches or throws the exception?

Comment: @acidnbass both. They will have separate TXs after adding the annotations.

Comment: the issue illustration with simple code can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312020/355438

Answer (score 33):

The answer of Shyam was right. I already faced with this issue before. It's not a problem, it's a SPRING feature. "Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only" is acceptable.

***Conclusion***

- USE REQUIRES_NEW if you want to commit what did you do before exception (Local commit)
- USE REQUIRED if you want to commit only when all processes are done (Global commit) And you just need to ignore "Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only" exception. But you need to try-catch out side the caller processNextRegistrationMessage() to have a meaning log.

Let's me explain more detail:

**Question: How many Transaction we have? Answer: Only one**

Because you config the PROPAGATION is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED so that the @Transaction persist() is using the same transaction with the caller-processNextRegistrationMessage(). Actually, when we get an exception, the Spring will set **rollBackOnly** for the TransactionManager so the Spring will rollback just only one Transaction.

**Question: But we have a try-catch outside (), why does it happen this exception?
 Answer Because of unique Transaction**

1. When persist() method has an exception
2. Go to the catch outside

   ```
   Spring will set the rollBackOnly to true -> it determine we must 
   rollback the caller (processNextRegistrationMessage) also.
   ```
3. The persist() will rollback itself first.
4. Throw an UnexpectedRollbackException to inform that, we need to rollback the caller also.
5. The try-catch in run() will catch UnexpectedRollbackException and print the stack trace

**Question: Why we change PROPAGATION to REQUIRES_NEW, it works?**

Answer: Because now the processNextRegistrationMessage() and persist() are in the different transaction so that they only rollback their transaction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to rollback your transactions on `ProcessIncomingMessageException` exception, then you can pass `noRollbackFor` and `rollbackFor` in your `@Transactional` annotation as shown below:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = Exception.class, rollbackFor = ProcessIncomingMessageException.class)
public void processNextRegistrationMessage() throws ProcessIncomingMessageException {
        String refrenceId = null;
        MessageTypeEnum registrationMessageType = MessageTypeEnum.REGISTRATION;
        try {
            //code that may result in an exception
            ....
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof ProcessIncomingMessageException) {
                throw (ProcessIncomingMessageException) e;
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            // send error outgoing-message
            ....
        }
    }
```

Please note that Spring `@Transactional` will automatically rollback the transaction for all `RuntimeExceptions` and its subclasses, however, it won't rollback in case of checked exceptions. The aforementioned parameters allow programmers to override that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This error could appear because of an exception thrown before in a database and the rollback is required for consistency purpose when working with transactions. For example, when using Hibernate entities, forgetting to set the parent for the child entity will throw this error even when saving into the database the parent of the parent of the forgotten child, all encompassed in the same transaction. Another example is the incorrect name of a table that is mapped onto an entity.