# Does hibernate rollback transaction for exception that is being handled in the caller method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, backend

I know that hibernate will rollback all the changes made inside a @Transactional annotated method if any exception occurs inside it.

I am also aware that if we handle the exception with try catch then hibernate won't perform transaction rollback operation.

My question is that will hibernate perform transaction rollback if I handle the exception with try catch from the caller method (The method which invoked the database update operation method annotated with @Transactional)??

Comment: Hibernate does not handle the transaction, the Transaction Manager does.

Comment: Give it a try and you will find out. It is the best way to learn ;)

Comment: @JoãoDias thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Also be aware that Spring's @Transactional annotation will only cause rollback on a RuntimeException. Checked Exceptions will not cause a rollback.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125837/why-does-transaction-roll-back-on-runtimeexception-but-not-sqlexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Well after testing it out myself I found out that even if you handle an exception from the caller method the transaction will roll back.**

If anyone wondering what will happen if the caller method itself has transactional annotation in it? It will throw this exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
```

The reason for it is explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349898/unexpectedrollbackexception-transaction-rolled-back-because-it-has-been-marked)