# Spring transaction not rolled back after an exception is thrown

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data, spring-transactions

I have a service with a method, which is not annotated with `@Transactional`:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MainService {

    private final ServiceA serviceA;    

    public void processData() {
        List<EntityA> list = serviceA.getList();
        list.forEach(item -> {
        try {
            serviceA.doSomeDbOperations(item);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // some processing here
        } finally {
            // some processing and DB interactions here
        }
        })
    }

}
```

The goal is to roll back the changes happened in try block (`serviceA.doSomeDbOperations(item)`) if an exception is thrown. so I annotated this method in ServiceA with `@Transactional`:

```
@Service
public class ServiceA {
    // dependencies

    @Transactional
    public void doSomeDbOperations(EntityA item) {
        // some logic here
        repositoryA.save(item)
        serviceB.deleteSomething(input)
    }
}
```

`serviceB.deleteSomething(input)` could throw an exception:

```
@Service
public class ServiceB {
    // dependencies
    
    public void deleteSomething(EntityA item) {
        // some logic here
        if(condition) {
            Throw new RuntimeException();
        }        
    }
}
```

The problem is that when an Exception is thrown, the changes in try block are not rolled back and data is non-consistent. Any idea where the problem is?

Comment: Could you please confirm that the ServiceA and ServiceB are also annotated with the @Service annotation?

Comment: [Rolling back a declarative transaction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html): "Checked exceptions that are thrown from a transactional method do not result in rollback in the default configuration"

Comment: @cdr89 yes they are. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in ServiceB you are using a checked Exception.
In Spring the transactions are rolled back just on unchecked exceptions by default, so try throwing for example a RuntimeException in your ServiceB.deleteSomething() method.

In case you need a checked Exception there, you can do something like this in your ServiceA.doSomeDbOperations() method:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
```

Some references:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-checked-unchecked-exceptions

[How to make Spring @Transactional roll back on all uncaught exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528178/how-to-make-spring-transactional-roll-back-on-all-uncaught-exceptions)

Comment: I updated the question again. I am actually throwing a RuntimeException. I also added the rollbackFor but the same problem exists.

Comment: @MehdiB if rollbackFor is included, it should work. what database are you running on? some db does not support transaction or not enabled.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 11.14

Comment: @MehdiB, is your doSomeDbOperations() method really public or has another visibility?