# javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have methodA calling methodB. MethodB  throwing some exception. What i want even if there some exception in methodB there is no rollback . I can not change
methodB. Is there a way to handle at methodA level ?

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
methodA() {
    ...
    try {

    for(Employee emp : employees){
          methodB();
        }
    } catch (...) {...}
    log("OK");
}

@Transactional
methodB() {
    // some exception is thrown
}
```

There is similar thread at [Transaction marked as rollback only: How do I find the cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302196/transaction-marked-as-rollback-only-how-do-i-find-the-cause) but looks like accepeted answer handled it at methodB level instead of calling method ?

Comment: you can achieve this if method B and method A has different Exception throwing possibilities, write catch blocks in method A for the exceptions thrown by method B and handle it(don't rollback here)