# hibernate rollback error message is not clear

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

i write multiple inner transactional method that all of them are in on transaction.

```
 @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
 A(){

  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
   b() {
          //and so on ...
    }
}
```

every error that has occured every where in methods is the same:"Transaction marked as rollback only"!
how can i see the main detail error  and show it to the client until it be clear that exactly what happend?

Comment: this error message means that you caught an exception and further down you tried to commit. Also no need to mark the @Transactional at class and method level with same propagation. At class level it cascades to all methods inside.

Comment: it's not my answer!i want a way to find out the right reason for roll back and will back it to the client

Comment: I think the first answer in this link can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302196/transaction-marked-as-rollback-only-how-do-i-find-the-cause