# JPA ERROR: Invalid operation for forward only resultset : absolute

Tags: jpa, oracle11g, criteria

I am trying to get the rows with `Criteria JPA`:

my relation is:

[image]

```java
class Photo { 
  ...

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "GALLERY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  private Gallery gallery;

  ...
}
```

and my DAO is:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Photo> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Photo.class);
Root<Photo> root = criteriaQuery.from(Photo.class);

List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();

GalleryCriteria gallery = criteria.getGallery();
if (Validator.isNotNull(gallery)) {
    Long galleryId = gallery.getId();
    Predicate predicate = builder.equal(root.<Gallery>get(Photo_.gallery), galleryId);
    predicateList.add(predicate);
}

Predicate predicate = builder.equal(root.<String>get(Photo_.deleted), "ACTIVE");
predicateList.add(predicate);

criteriaQuery.select(root);
criteriaQuery.where(builder.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[predicateList.size()])));
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
query.setFirstResult(criteria.getFirstResult());
query.setMaxResults(criteria.getMaxResults());

List<Photo> photos = (PHOTO) query.getResultList();
```

my query is:
select distinct generatedAlias0 from Photo as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.gallery=5L ) and ( generatedAlias0.deleted=:param0 ).

but im getting an `ERROR: Invalid operation for forward only resultset : absolute` error. thanks

stack trace is :

```
ERROR: Invalid operation for forward only resultset : absolute
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:314)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:540)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:742)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:710)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:556)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:298)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.findByCriteria(Unknown Source)
    at ir.com.gallery.application.controller.GalleryController.pagingPhoto(GalleryController.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace and the mark the location where it occurs.

Comment: @JensSchauder Unfortunately that doesn't has any stack trace :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transaction marked as rollback only: How do I find the cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302196/transaction-marked-as-rollback-only-how-do-i-find-the-cause)

Comment: @JensSchauder the parent classes are ```@transaction```, ```@service``` and  ```@repository``` too. can you speak more clearly. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understand the problem, our frontend developer doesn't set first and max result in criteria. and default value was -1 for both of the them.

```
if ( criteria.getFirstResult() == -1 ) {
    criteria.setFirstResult(0);
}

if ( criteria.getMaxResults() == -1 ) {
    criteria.setMaxResults(10);
}
```