Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException
What might be a root cause of below error? I am using Spring, Hibernate, Postgresql.
2024-04-02 11:05:34.035 [acquiring_push_notify_scheduler-10] ERROR o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy868.validateExpiredProfiles(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:217)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
        ... 22 common frames omitted

I have a method, which takes profiles from db and updates them:
    @Override
    @Transactional("mainTx")
    public void validateExpiredProfiles() {
             List<ProfileData> profiles = verifiedCashierDao.getVerifiedCashiersWithExpiredProfile(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(NOTIFY_DAY_BEFORE));
        LOGGER.info("validateExpiredProfiles: Size of expired profiles {}", profiles.size());

        for (ProfileData profile : profiles) {
            try{
                agentDao.changeCashierIdentification(profile.getCashierId(), IdentificationStatusEnum.PROFILE_DATA_EXPIRED);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                LOGGER.error("Error on validateExpiredProfiles {} cause {}", profile.getPhone(), e);
            }
        }
    }

In spring xml context file:
<task:scheduled ref="verifiedCashierService" method="validateExpiredProfiles" cron="0 0/5 * * * *" />

Try this comment the bean named with mainTx, as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31228177/8374909, you will get the exact root cause

@Clover I don't think he even needs to do this. It's very likely already logged by the catch block the OP posted.

looping with a try/catch. There is an exception, which will render the session and transaction unusable, thus it will be marked for rollback. But as you are looping and catching and swallowing (i.e.not re-throwing the exception) this error will eventually trigger the exception you get as the transaction support thinks everything was ok (it didn't get an exception) and tries to commit a tx that was marked for rollback.

The message basically tells you what the problem is: "Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit" - the failing piece of code tries to commit a transaction that already was marked as failed and to be rolled back. Now the question is why does that happen.
Without knowing more about your system I'd say this is because of an exception you're getting, catching and logging in your code.
Let me try to illustrate that:
          --- 1 --->                          --- 2 ---> 
Scheduler            validateExpiredProfiles()           agentDao.changeCashierIdentification(...)
          <--- 1 ---                          <--- 2 ---


The interceptor at 1 starts the transaction and calls validateExpiredProfiles().
That in turn calls agentDao.changeCashierIdentification(...) at which point interceptor 2 kicks in.
Interceptor 2 sees an already running transaction so doesn't do anything but forward the call.
agentDao.changeCashierIdentification(...) throws some exception which is picked up by interceptor 2. This interceptor sees "a problem" and marks the transaction as rollback only.
validateExpiredProfiles() catches the exception so interceptor 1 doesn't know about it. Thus it tries to commit the transaction it starts which then fails with the exception you posted.

To solve this I'd say you have at least the following options:

Check your log for the exception you logged and fix it. You probably can't prevent all exceptions so that's just curing a symptom.
Rethrow the exception after logging it. Of course now the same exception might get logged multiple times.
Configure the interceptors and tell them which exceptions do not lead to a rollback (e.g. so called "application exceptions"). A default might already be in place so consult the documentation. Your code might also want to treat those exceptions differently, i.e. catch and log application exceptions and not catch or rethrow any others.


Thank you a lot, your recomendation helped me to fix the issue.
